# How to avoid adding comma at the end of input type element in Html?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am using a HTML5 input box with type="**text**" with bootstrap class "**form-control**" . while giving the values in input , it automatically appends the comma value in the text , because of this my client side validation became fails . Can you please suggest, how to avoid this behavior.

Without bootstrap element it is working properly . After adding the bootstrap only i am facing this problem.

In UI, I  entered the value as **547132**, but in client side i am getting the value as "**547132,**".

```html
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <input class="form-control" id="bin" type="text" th:field="*{bin}" maxlength="10" onclick="hideFunction()"
            onchange="InvalidMsg(this);" required autocomplete="off" pattern="[0-9]{6,10}">
    </div>
```

JS functionality:-

```
    function InvalidMsg(textbox) {
        console.log(textbox.value);
        var patt1 = /^[0-9]*$/g;
        if (textbox.value.length < 6) {
            console.log(textbox.value.length);
            textbox
                    .setCustomValidity('Bin should be 6 or 10 characters in length !');
        } else if (!textbox.value.match(patt1)) {
            console.log(textbox.value.length);
            textbox.setCustomValidity('Bin should be only numbers');
        } else {
            textbox.setCustomValidity('');
        }
        return true;
    }

    function hideFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("errorMessage");
        if (null!=x) {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

---

[image]

Comment: This is the problem of your method `hideFunction()` or `InvalidMsg()`. Please share your JS code also.

Comment: Hi Piyush, I added the comment.

Comment: Your code is working fine I am not getting `547132,` I got the value `547132`

Comment: Thanks Piyush, i added the same model twice in the UI pager , because of that i am getting comma . Issue has been fixed .